# Simple HTML forms action

Tags: html, forms, submit, action

Hopefully a simple question here. If in HTML I have a form like this:

```
<form name="f_input" action="Test="+num target="TargetFrame" method="get">
Set Number: <input type="text" name="num" value="10">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When I click the button it goes (in the separate TargetFrame frame) to "Test=?num=10". I want it to go to "Test=10", how do I do that?

Comment: You need to pass the extension as well for the page name if your intention is to go to that page, else the behavior is correct, if you don't define the page name, it will add the get param

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use the normal behavior of going to `Test?num=10`? Maybe use a rewrite rule on the server to convert that to what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML forms do not provide that capability.

The closest you could get would be:

```
action="/"
```

and

```
name="Test" value="10"
```

which would give you: `/?Test=10`

---

If you really want just `Test=10` then you would have to use JavaScript to capture the submit event of the form and override the normal form behaviour. This adds a dependancy on JavaScript so is not a good idea. It would be better to modify the server side of the program to handle the standard form submission schemes.

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener("submit", customSubmission);

function customSubmission(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    document.frames.TargetFrame.src = "Test=" + encodeURIComponent(this.elements.num.value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Quentin. I'll do what you suggest and fix it on the Server side, the system will be better for it. I wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something, and I don't want to add JavaScript. Thank you for your help.